# Remove parent div if duplicate words

Tags: each, jquery

I'm using a service called [Embedly](http://embed.ly/) to style my RSS feeds from Google Feedburner. I have an example code over her: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VBSX/25/)

If you look closely you will see the source (CNN) at the end of every title. This is called `.provider` I would like to get rid of the whole div (.embed) IF the the word CNN is located elsewere (meaning duplicate) in the div, either `.description` or `a`

I tried many things, this is one of them really straight forward code:

```
    $('.embed').each(function() {
    if($('.embed a:first **could also be .description**', this).text() == $('.provider', this).text())
        $(this).remove();
});
```

I cant figure out why its not working. I also used it with `on` and `live` click with no luck.

I just realized the 'embeds' are not there on document tready. I added a button with click event which you can click after the embedly has loaded in: http://jsfiddle.net/2VBSX/37/

Comment: Can you please show the representative/minimal mark-up you're working with?

Comment: @David Thomas I don't understand your question. Everything 'Im working with' is in the JsFiddle

Comment: Ah, so when (not *if*) JS Fiddle next falls over your happy for us all to be entirely unable to provide any help, and for the question to become meaningless? Stack Overflow is meant to be self-contained to prevent against link-rot, link to external demos, references and resources by all means, but the question should stand here.

Comment: So do you want to get rid of div.embed when you get (CNN) in it?

Comment: Try removing `.embed` from your selector: ==> `'.embed a:first`, _"Everything 'Im working with' is in the JsFiddle"_ So where is the `.embed` element in your jsfiddle?

Comment: I just realized the 'embeds' are not there on document tready. I added a button with click event which you can click after the embedly has loaded in: http://jsfiddle.net/2VBSX/37/

Comment: @David Thomas So that would mean one can not give url to some jquery file but instead post the complete file

Comment: No, it means your question should be self contained with enough detail(s) that we can answer it *without* looking elsewhere. Demos are nice, but they're not (in most cases) essential. The whole point is that we should be able to answer, and to help you, by looking at your question without having to go elsewhere. Certainly as regards JS Fiddle which, though it's a wonderful resource, has a tendency to fall over on a regular basis.

Comment: Changes are very small you could answer this question without looking at the demo because of the services included which trigger the data (Feedburner, Embedly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use success event to filter provider class from the data like this :

**EDITED**

```
  $('div.newscontainer').embedly({
    key: ':3eccf441bf0f43acbb076da9817af27d',
    success: function(oembed, dict) {

        output = $(oembed['code']);
        description = $(oembed['code']).find(".description").text();           
        var regex =new RegExp(output.find('.provider').text(),"i");
        if(regex.exec(description) == null ) {              
            $(dict["node"]).parent().html(output);
        }

        output.find("a:eq(0)").text(); // First
        output.find("a:eq(1)").text(); // Provider


    }
});
```

Checkout this  [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/YrnyP/)

Comment: It doesn't find the duplicate and remove the parent div .embed...That is what my question was about. But maybe I misunderstood..

Comment: I can remove `.provider` with jquery `$remove` or `display:none`

Comment: I edit my answer . Checkout demo again. But i dont get it one thing . what we have suppose to see in this situation? There is nothing left cause all li elements  contain the provider text. Is this true?

Comment: Hi, thanks for sticking around:) Yes you are correct, in this case there would be nothing left. I need it to work like this for my project, in the end I will be able to 'filter' content. However when I go to the fiddle I still see the Feedburner links, which is strange because if the embedly process works they are going to be transformed in to .embed...It looks to me like the embedly process never took place..

Comment: Ok. I made mistake i edited again but that doesnt change the result. Make sure that you look last state. There is nothing left in demo.

Comment: One last question do you need to get rid of orginal script lines if the condition is true? Cause  i didnt touch them.

Comment: Hi, I think this will work as it is. Im not really using feedburner links, I just put them up as an example. I accept your anwser, thank you very much:) If you could do me one small favor...I actually need to  compare the first link with .provider and do the filtering. As it is now its is filtering everything. I would really appreciate if you could show me how to do that..

Comment: Hi your code doesn't seem to work after all.....Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/YrnyP/8/ You will see an url to an article. The provider name is `Nu` This word is not to be found in the article anyware, but when I integrate your code the complete article is being removed. It shouldn't...

Comment: It should only be removed if a duplicate (in this case 'Nu') is found elsewere in the article

Comment: You can get first and provider link like this :      output.find("a:eq(0)").text(); // First
output.find("a:eq(1)").text(); // Provider

Comment: I'm accepting your answer for all your input, but it doesn't work, the article is still being removed http://jsfiddle.net/YrnyP/9/  To bad:( thanks anyway

Comment: You are right. I updated the link. Check again. Previosly i compared All data with provider. Now i compare only description with provider. It should resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Its working:) (do you know how to remove the parent div instead of the .description...)

Comment: I dont get it. I didnt remove description there. I just skip the embed process for that item if the condition is true. Which is the same thing you desire. (Removing parent)

Comment: I don't get it either but than again I only know jquery:)

Comment: Hmm i inspect orginal data.There is no description for that link. Its empty. You think that it removed when you see nothing.

Comment: Thats true, no description. Nevertheless there are five urls in my example. only the first one is embedded with title an .provider. I see the the same thing in my big project with a hundred urls. Only one of them is getting the embed, it doesnt add up.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment. Thank you very very much for all your time and effort. I have been stressing out for two whole days one this, cant thank you enough

Answer (score 0):

Is it [that](http://jsfiddle.net/muffls/h4Wkq/) what you want?

```
var regex = /CNN/;
$('.embed').each(function(index, element) {

    if (regex.exec($('.embed a:first').text()) != null 
       && regex.exec($('.provider').text()) != null) {
        element.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: This code stops the embedly process. I can see that because if the div.embed was removed there would be no feedburner links. The links are 'transformed' in the embed. So I see the links which means the embedly didn't take place.

Comment: Please look at my qeustion I added a button

Comment: Maybe the whole thing is case sensitive...??